# How to implement Custom UserStore (or custom authentication) in ASP.NET Core (not older versions!)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to build new website with ASP.NET Core 1 (May 2016), and I need to implement different kind of sign-in procedures (not with SQL Server).

So I am trying implement `MyOwnUserStore`, where I want to override login procedures, but when I start the application the result is this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'LoginWebApp04.Services.MyOwnUserStore'.

My code is simple, new class:

```
public class MyOwnUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyOwnUserStore(DbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

and modification of `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    var idt = services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>();
    idt.AddUserStore<MyOwnUserStore>();  // <-------------------------- HERE
    idt.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    idt.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

I have changed nothing else in my new project, and the project is created as ASP.NET Core Web Application with authentication = individual user accounts.

So what I need to do more to make the first run of my app without exception?

I have tried many examples from internet but all I have found are outdated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DI framework doesn't know what to resolve for the user store. Change `DbContext` in the constructor to `ApplicationDbContext`

```
public class MyOwnUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser> {
    public MyOwnUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Change the order of when you add the user store. You need to add entity framework stored before adding user store.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services
        .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddUserStore<MyOwnUserStore>()  // <----MOVED AFTER ADDING EF STORES
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Comment: What if my UserId is int . I get error  The type 'RED.Models.Security.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'RED.Models.Security.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser<string>'

Answer (score 0):

in Core 3.1 to upper Use the code

```
public class MyOwnUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser> {
    public MyOwnUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer) {
    }
    ...
}


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services
        .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddUserStore<MyOwnUserStore>()  // <----MOVED AFTER ADDING EF STORES
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

 services.AddSingleton<MyOwnUserStore>();   <----- ADDING THIS DEP


}
```