# .Net 6 Dependency Injection custom identity storage provider Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im trying to use ASP.NET Core Identity with a custom storage provider, and using dapper instead of entity framework core in my .Net 6 api. I followed the following link from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0

This Code snippet is from my controller

```
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AuthController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RegisterUser>> Register(RegisterUser user)
        {

            var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = user.Username
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.Password);

            return new RegisterUser();

        }
```

This is my models

```
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityRole
    {

    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
    {
        
    }
```

This is code is from CustomUserStore.cs

```
    public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

        public CustomUserStore(IDbConnection dbConnection)
        {
            _dbConnection = dbConnection;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            //Dapper code for data access
            ....
```

My Program.cs for dependency injection registration

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>()
        .AddUserStore<CustomUserStore>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I also tried to create IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions class,

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

as microsoft referredin their documentiation in the link provided in the top.

But im getting the following error

**Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser,identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.)   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.                                                                                                                                                                                                    ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[identityWithOutEF.ApplicationUserRole]'.**

I dont get this error when using asp.net core 3.1 but only when using .Net 6.
Can someone help me and tell me what im doing wrong or can provided some example on how to do this in .Net 6
Thank you.

Comment: I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632392/how-to-implement-custom-userstore-or-custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core-no) can give you some help.

Comment: Thank you for the provided link, but they seems to use entity framework core im trying to use dapper and having some issues with dependency injection.

Comment: Sound like `IRoleStore` is required. Just add the service.